# Android Studio can't see module after import

Tags: android

Android Studio “beta” 0.8.6
on 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
Problem:
When importing source code from various sources either gradle based or eclipse based in to Android Studio the source code is missing from the project view.
Screen shot post import “project” in Android Studio.
![enter image description here][1]

Screen shot of files within the project using Nautilus.

Note Nautilus clearly shows the source code, Gradle, IDE files. Android Studio shows the Gradle files only.

The event log event log:

Error running app: Module is not found

So I tried to put the source code into the project using:

Android Studio main menu → File → New Module
AND
Android Studio main menu → File → Import Module

Tried  most of the possible combinations in New Module and Import Module.
All the combinations Gave:

“This Location is already imported” within the Module Wizard.

So how do I get the source code in to the project?

These problems with Gradle are beyond annoying and approaching the the R Object disaster in eclipse. Where none of the build sequences repeat with any reasonable consistency.

Thank you in advance for your help, ultra disgusted Mark.
Sorry about lack of images.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to WORK!
Used the command line, terminal described at:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-build.html
Section of that page titled “Build the project from the command line” has instruction for all three operating systems.
C louse Android Studio, for some reason having it open interfers with the gradlew on my system anyway.
On Ubuntu Linux.
In GNOME Terminal.
Navigate to the folder containing the project.
Enter: chmod +x gradlew
    gradlew is the gradle wrapper.
    If your project is missing the gradlew file use the Wizard in Android   Studio to make a separate project and copy the gradlew file to the folder   where you are working. 
    The chmod +x makes the gradlew executable, need to be run once for  each project.
The project Should build, if you get errors do your best to look them up and fix them.

Once I did the above and imported in to Android Studio the project worked perfect in with in the IDE and even ran in an AVD.

Beyond me how the command line works fine and the IDE cause nothing but grief and extreme aggravation (~ two days in my case).

SO if Android Studio will not import or open a project try the command line. Give that you have the proper build.gradle files (between the android plug in changing the stuff that goes in build.gradle changes as well so it a Screaming Nightmare to keep up with it).

I hope that helped somebody out. Mark

Comment: `chmod +x gradlew` then import project worked! thanks